# Hebrew-to-Greek translation of birth narrative's "virgin"

Tags: greek, translation-philosophy

I've been going through a list of words and phrases that were possibly mistranslated from Hebrew to Greek, Old Testament to New Testament.

The one that stood out to me with great significance is how the word *virgin* came about in the NT. As I understand it, there are two (?) or so words for the concept of a virgin in Hebrew and many more in Greek (five or six?). They all have very similar meanings.

So what Hebrew word for the concept of a virgin was most likely used and how was the Greek translation chosen? I apologize if I have this who thing backwards. It's a pretty muddy area for me.